# Elementos que retornam ao tamanho original quando clicados novamente ou quando um elemento irmão é clicado

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

Eu tenho uma tabela com alguns `<td>` que se alinham verticalmente. Quando clicado, a altura do `<td>` aumenta, e se for clicado outro `<td>`, o anterior volta ao tamanho original. Também preciso que o elemento volte ao tamanho original quando clicado novamente.

Até agora, eu só consegui mudar a altura no 1º clique:

```
$('#tabela_funcoes td').click(function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '300px'
  }, "slow" )
})
```

Comment: Um **toggleClass** não resoveria? [http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O evento de clique é na linha (`<tr>`) e você consegue pegar todos os irmãos do elemento clicado para restaurar a altura. Depois, aumenta a altura do elemento clicado. Bootply com o teste: https://www.bootply.com/FAoXyzLzGd

```js
$('#teste tbody tr').on('click', function() {
  $(this)
    .siblings()
    .animate({
      height: '50px'
    });

  $(this).animate({
    height: '150px'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="teste" class="table table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Coluna 1</th>
      <th>Coluna 2</th>
      <th>Coluna 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr style="height: 50px">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 50px">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 50px">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 50px">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 50px">
      <td>Valor 1</td>
      <td>Valor 2</td>
      <td>Valor 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado!! Quando eu colocava o click sobre o td, tinha um delay antes do bloco aumentar de tamanho. Você sabe explicar por quê?

Aliás: existe alguma forma de eu controlar o lado para o qual o elemento se expande? Pois quando eu clico nos de baixo, a parte de cima também se move empurrando o elemento de cima, o que incomoda um pouco visualmente

Comment: Ah! E o tamanho do bloco não volta ao normal quando novamente clicado. Preciso usar o if, como na resposta do outro colega?

Comment: Atualizei o bootply para pegar a altura inicial. Quando o documento é carregado, o código criar uma variável chamada 'initialHeight' com a altura inicial das linhas, sendo utilizada futuramente para voltar à altura original.

Comment: Sobre a direção da expansão, não acredito que exista. Se existir, eu desconheço. O que acontece é que são elementos alinhados na vertical. Se você aumentar o tamanho, é necessário empurrar os de baixo para baixo. Quando diminui, naturalmente vc puxa eles pra cima (no caso, os de baixo vão ficar parados, pois outro vai aumentar o tamanho e manter eles na mesma posição). Testei com a segunda linha expandida e expandi a terceira, na sequência. As linhas de baixo ficam estáticas.